# How do I set Windows Update to never check for updates with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm looking for help scripting with PowerShell, Windows Server 2008 R2 so Windows Updates is set to "Never check for updates."  I found some near answers but I still can't do what I want.  Currently, I have to set it by clicking Windows Update > Change Settings > Never Check for Updates.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a COM object for that :

```
$WUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
$WUSettings
NotificationLevel         : 2
ReadOnly                  : True
Required                  : False
ScheduledInstallationDay  : 0
ScheduledInstallationTime : 3
IncludeRecommendedUpdates : True
NonAdministratorsElevated : True
FeaturedUpdatesEnabled    : True
```

With :

```
NotificationLevel  :
0 = Not configured;
1 = Disabled;
2 = Notify before download;
3 = Notify before installation;
4 = Scheduled installation;
```

You can test :

```
$WUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
$WUSettings.NotificationLevel=1
$WUSettings.save()
```

---

**(Edited)**

You must use a PowerShell session run as administrator in an elevated mode.

Comment: As of Windows Server 2016, this doesn't work anymore.