# Error when setting Windows Updates preferences from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried following the suggestion here([How do I set Windows Update to never check for updates with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612609/how-do-i-set-windows-update-to-never-check-for-updates-with-powershell)), and it's very straight forward. Everything seems to be working until I get to the part where I need to actually change the NotificationLevel value. I get the following error:

 `Exception setting "NotificationLevel": "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240037"
At line:1 char:1
+ $WUSettings.NotificationLevel=1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValueTI`
I tried running the same sequence on another Windows 7 Pro computer and got a slightly different error message:
`Exception setting "NotificationLevel": "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240037"
At line:1 char:13
+ $WUSettings. <<<< NotificationLevel=1
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException`
The only difference that I noticed was that I'm trying to do this on Windows 7 Pro instead of Windows Server 2008 R2. This is my first venture into using PowerShell and this looked fairly simply, but I'm now quickly out of my depth. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're in an Active Directory environment, you'd probably be better off doing this via GPO.

Comment: @alroc We're working with a mixed environment, in this case a GPO isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in my logs from 2012 :

Can you try to remove the NoAutoUpdate key in :

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

---

Edited

I reproduce your problem, you just forget to run your PowerShell as administrator (elevated mode) :

[image]

versus

[image]

Comment: Is it possible he needs to run under 32 bit PS since we are dealing with COM objects?

Comment: My W2K8 R2 were all 64 bits and I use 64 bits PowerShell.

Comment: I've had issues with COM libraries needing to run in 32 bit mode.

Comment: @JPBlanc I tried deleting that key and running in 32bit mode as well. I'm still getting the same error. I also tried this on a clean Windows 7 Pro SP 1 install with PowerShell 3, I'm getting the first error I listed in my initial question.

Comment: @infinit_e I edit My answer, I reproduce your problem with a PowerShell session, not started as administrator (elevated mode).

Comment: @JPBlanc Nothing special for PowerShell to run as administrator right? Right-Click, Run as Admin? I tried that, and tried doing the same under the local admin account. I still get the same error.

Comment: @infinit_e I can only reproduce you problem, when I'am on a non elevated mode. There is something wrong with UAC.

Comment: @JPBlanc You were right about the UAC. We have some local group policy objects that get applied during an image that were apparently interfering. I nuked System32\GroupPolicy, did a GPUpdate, and tried again. It worked fine.

Comment: Has anyone narrowed down what about UAC is preventing this? Deleting System32\GroupPolicy and running gpuupdate.exe did in fact get me around this error, but it doesn't feel like a solution I can use in the tool I'm building and I don't control the images it has to work on. Also, how safe is it to delete the contents of that directory? (Testing on a VM, so I have some room to experiment.)

Comment: Actually, as an addendum - the delete System32\GroupPolicy contents + gpupdate.exe trick only worked on my 32-bit Win7 VM. It didn't get me past the error on 64-bit Win10 tech preview (and my SysWOW64\GroupPolicy folder was empty.)

Comment: Sorry, last comment. No trouble with this on a new install of 8.1 Industry. Error code 0x80240037 is WU_E_NOT_SUPPORTED, which leads me to believe this just isn't supported in the Win10 tech preview for reasons which seem fairly clear; not sure why I wasn't thinking of that.

Comment: The first 3 lines of the answer worked for me. I had created these as part of [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328010/how-to-configure-automatic-updates-by-using-group-policy-or-registry-s) solution but after removing the keys the PowerShell way worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with the domain Group Policy controlling updates (Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update). It's basically the same as when the user goes to Windows Update > Change Settings and sees some elements grayed out and the message "Some settings are managed by your system administrator":  when Group Policy is set, you can't change settings locally.

Solution:

1. In that Group Policy, change all settings to "Not Configured".
2. Run **gpupdate** on the local computer.
3. Open a *new* administrative PowerShell prompt and try again.

Note:  I did not have to change anything related to UAC.