# Powershell, enable windows update error

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I'm trying to configure windows update with the Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate COM object with Powershell v4, on a Windows 2008 r2. I'm however running into a little trouble. When trying to set the NotificationLevel, I'm getting the following error (Note running with elevated permissions).

```
$WUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
$WUSettings.NotificationLevel=4
$WUSettings.save()
```

Output:

> Exception setting "NotificationLevel": "Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80240037" At line:1 char:1
>   + $WUSettings.NotificationLevel=4
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValueTI

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: as a  workaround you could change this setting in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` ( AUOptions entry )

Comment: or maybe you can use this module https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc

Comment: Possible a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486213/error-when-setting-windows-updates-preferences-from-powershell)....